# Box SDK Api to Delete (all but current versions) of a file

Tags: box-api

I basically want to delete all versions except for the currently designated version of the file.

For that I am using 
    `BoxClient.getFilesManager().getFileVersions(_fileId, reqObj);`

The first entry in the returned `List<BoxFileVersion>` object is the current version.

There doesn't seem to be any API in the Box SDK (for Java) to delete a version - is this being planned soon ? 
Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK is open-sourced on [github](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2).  If you feel like it, you can submit a pull request with your change to add in version delete.  How to do it is documented in the API documentation.